# Importing components through a custom Angular Material module

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-material2

Complying with recommended best practices, I import all Angular Material modules I intend to use into a custom module:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import {
    MatIconModule,
    MatChipsModule,
    MatCardModule,
    MatGridListModule,
    MatMenuModule,
    MatToolbarModule,
    MatSidenavModule,
    MatListModule,
    MatTableModule,
    MatTabsModule,
    MatInputModule,
    MatDialogModule,
    MatButtonModule
} from '@angular/material';
import { FlexLayoutModule } from '@angular/flex-layout';

const dependencyArray = [
    // Angular Material
    MatIconModule,
    MatCardModule,
    MatGridListModule,
    MatMenuModule,
    MatToolbarModule,
    MatSidenavModule,
    MatListModule,
    MatTableModule,
    MatTabsModule,
    MatInputModule,
    MatDialogModule,
    MatButtonModule,
    MatChipsModule,

    // flex
    FlexLayoutModule
];

/**
 * Imports needed Angular Material/flex dependencies.
 */
@NgModule({
    imports: dependencyArray,
    exports: dependencyArray
})

export class MaterialModule { }
```

When it comes to importing components (things like `MatDialogRef`), though, I'm not sure what to do:

```
export class MyComponent implements OnInit {
    selection: string;
    count: number;
    dialogRef: MatDialogRef<ServerDialogComponent>;
}
```

All examples on the Internet that use an import module ([including Angular Material itself!](https://github.com/angular/material2/blob/master/src/demo-app/dialog/dialog-demo.ts)) import components straight from `@angular/material`, which seems counter to the point of an import module. My expectation is that these too should pass through my `MaterialModule`, but I haven't found a procedure that works. One recommendation was to add `declarations: [MatDialogRef]` to `MaterialModule`'s body. Another was to add `entryComponents: [MatDialogRef]` instead. Another still was to just outright import/export the component like a module. None of those solutions work. TypeScript complains each time, 'Cannot find name "MatDialogRef"'.

What's the best practice for importing Angular Material components? Can it be done through a module like I have already? Or should I be importing straight from `@angular/material`?

Comment: did you figure out how to use it on components? i'm facing the same issue

Comment: in my case, i need to import that module in the exact module of my component, not in the main module

Comment: @PauloGaldoSandoval I ended up taking Mitch Lamers' advice and importing directly from @angular/material.

Comment: i've already do the module like they said, just need to import on the module that you will use the material components no on the main module

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The big difference here is the way of sharing angular modules and typescript importing.

By exporting a component from your angular module it can be used in HTML of the module you imported it into. But if you want to import the component into typescript you need to reference the actual file as typescripts needs this to compile the component's code.

So you will have to import it from @angular/material

Answer (score 0):

In your component, you need to import the module from angular material for typescript. In your case i will be as below:

`import {MatDialogRef}  from '@angular/material';`

Please try this and share updates.